# Evaluating the quotient of Dedekind Eta function

Tags: math-software, class-field-theory

This expression I found in some research paper, which connects quotient of Dedekind eta function and ray class field of conductor N, which in turn gives the value of j-invariants.

For $K=\mathbb Q(i)$ and N=3$ (conductor), the discriminant of the order is -36.

Now, $ j_{1,3}(\tau)=\dfrac{\eta(\tau)^{12}}{\eta(3\tau)^{12}}$, where $\tau=i$.  I evaluated this expression in Pari/Gp, and I got the answer in decimals which I found wrong, if some one knows their reply will be of great help

Comment: redirect to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819074/how-to-evaluate-the-quotient-of-dedekind-eta-function-in-pari-gp